# Efficiently storing numeric values in SQL Server that can be a wide range of sizes?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in a SQL server database that stores numeric values. The issue is that sometimes the number is Billions, sometimes it's 1.355 E -16. I would set the numeric to be something huge like numeric(35,20) but I assumed that will make them all take up that much space in the database, and that seems like such a waste. Is there a way to do this efficiently, like how we use varchar when sometimes having short strings and other times having long strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version and edition of SQL Server? SQL Server 2005 SP2 introduced a `vardecimal` format [which is already deprecated in favour of using row and page compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Both `vardecimal` and compression require Enterprise Edition engine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that will depend on what you will be using the number for.

you could use FLOAT, which can store [float and real (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

```
float
- 1.79E+308 to -2.23E-308, 0 and 2.23E-308 to 1.79E+308
real
- 3.40E + 38 to -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 to 3.40E + 38
```

The reason why I say it depends on what you whish to achieve is

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly.

### [SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4602/0)

Now the discussion around which data type to choose is one spent over many a beer, but the rules will stay the same. It depends on the significance on certain bits to you.